# Downloading and storing images

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-fragments, android-volley

I am currently working with Fragments, one of my fragments is "User Profile" where the signed in user can edit and view their own profile. One of the requirements for this university project is that the user needs to be able to upload a profile picture and it should be allocated to their user profile and saved on the server (I am currently using Lampp on linux). I have the following questions:

1. When a user uploads an image using the Volley library (Android) does it first need to save the relative/absolute path of the image to the MySQL database, and then use this information to get the image in JSON format back onto the device, where it shall be cached?
2. I read online that the Volley library can cache images and videos on the device, which would help data consumption so the user doesn't need to download the image(s) every time they login again. But what if the user logs into the application from say an IOS device and uploads an image there and then they come back to the Android device and logs in there - the app needs to update their user profile.

My thinking was every time a new Image is uploaded to the server the time it was uploaded would be added to a Date/Time slot in the DB, then this time is stored is the SQlite DB and the MySQL DB, every time they open the application it makes a request to the MySQL DB requesting this time field and if no images have been added then the SQLite time and the one just pulled from the MySQL database will be the same so no need to download any images - I thought this would be a simple way of checking without using a lot of data? or is there a better option someone could suggest.

However, the problem with my above suggestion is say for example there are 5 images cached on the device, but a 6th one was added from another device, when we go back to the original device how do we only download the new image? and not all of the other 5 also which are already in the cache?

Comment: This is a whole lot of description of what you're trying to do and no hint as to what the actual specific problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think you need to store in db not path to image file, but URI that you pass into Volley. And then, when you want to show image pass saved URI in Volley and it will decide show cached image or upload from internet.
2. Good thoughts. I think in your case you can just show data cached in dp, and then additionally fetch data from server, and it was changed cache it and show new results. Also you can implements long polling, or sockets, or GCM to set up connection with server and fetch new updated data immediatelly (in real cases not immediatelly but faster then "go to app -> check from request if there was changes in server side").

And of course, please have a look to [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/) tutorials to think about implementing on your server side this thing and provide more interesting and covenient connection with immediate update of your local cached data. [additional link to video tutroial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B1rlT5KQ0yE)

Comment: I have some questions:

1. So you would suggest storing the actual image in the MySQL DB? We were always told in university not to do this for some reason. 

2. I do  not fully understand what you mean by 2. what do you mean by "show data cached in dp" do you mean show the image from the cache and also get from server? if you mean this wouldn't it reload all the  images again? which will use a lot of data. and for "implements long polling, or sockets, or GCM" would I just use firebase? thank you

Comment: 1. I suggest to store in db not image, but URI of image. For example it is URL  that you pass into Volley

Comment: 2. I mean that you have cached URI of image in dp, or cached info of user profile. Doesn't matter. Then you get this data from db. In case of images you get stored URI of image from db. Then show it with help of volley. Then make a request to server to fetch new information. Then if it changed cache this infomation in db and show updated information.